# Javascript can't get width of object image

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
    inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);
    function previewImages(){
        var fileList = this.files;
        var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

            for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
              var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);                  
              $('.preview-area').append('<img class="resizeme" id="myImage" height="150" src="' + objectUrl + '" + title="' + fileList[i].name + ' ( ' + fileList[i] + ' "/>');
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
            }
    }
```

i can get image name for title by this code

```
fileList[i].name
```

but when i try to  add width and height in title image by adding this code

```
fileList[i].width
fileList[i].height
```

it's give "**undefined**" result
i already try using `fileList[i].naturalWidth`
and it's give same result

what I'm missing?

---

**FLOW**

i try to created a multiple image preview before user press submit and upload image to server...i want every preview image has tooltip title which contains (name, width, height)
i already success get name in tooltip by

```
fileList[i].name
```

is it possible to get width and height of image too in tooltip title?

---

**ADD EVENT LISTENER INSIDE LOOP**

```
var inputLocalImage = document.getElementById("image-input");
    inputLocalImage.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);
    function previewImages(){
        var fileList = this.files;
        var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

            for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
              var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);                  

              objectUrl.addEventListener("load", function() {
                alert('objectUrl.width');  
              })

              $('.preview-area').append('<img class="resizeme" id="myImage" height="150" src="' + objectUrl + '" + title="' + fileList[i].name + ' (s ' + fileList[i].clientWidth + ' "/>');
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
            }
    }
```

I already try add event listener in 
*objectUrl / filename[i]*

with property 
*.width 

.naturalWidth 

.clientWidth*

What I'm missing?

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
      <label for="image" class="control-label col-lg-3">Image<span class="required">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
         <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
         <div class="preview-area"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

preview-area class is my container for multiple image preview...i append it by this code

```
$('.preview-area').append('<img class="resizeme" id="myImage" height="150" src="' + objectUrl + '" + title="' + fileList[i].name + ' ( ' + fileList[i] + ' "/>');
```

Comment: Try searching first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: This is just speculation since you are not showing where you are trying to access the dimensions (please create **complete** examples), but I assume you are accessing them before the image loaded (I think even data URLs have to be "loaded").

Comment: @Ace fileList[i].clientWidth still give undefined result

Comment: @FelixKling but i can get img name...if i can get img name doens't it mean image already loaded? i will try to update my question with flow..give me a few minutes

Comment: what is `$` in your code? are you using jquery?

Comment: @wahwahwah yeah i used jquery too...so i don't mind solution by javascript or jquery

Answer (score 1):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/pjf3uffs/3/

> **Note** :In this Example I don't have multiple image so i get width and
>   height when we click on image

And for changing width use   **inputLocalFont.style.width = '500px';**

And for getting Name of image :

```
var name = inputLocalFont.src;
var filename = name.split("/")[name.split("/").length-1];
```

---

```
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("click", previewImages, false);

function previewImages() {

    var width = inputLocalFont.clientWidth;
    var height = inputLocalFont.clientHeight;
    var name = inputLocalFont.src;
    inputLocalFont.style.width = '500px';
    alert("width:" + width + "height:" + height)
    var filename = name.split("/")[name.split("/").length - 1];
    console.log(filename)
}
```

Comment: hm actually "inputLocalFont" is var for browse button...so when it's change , then my script running previewImages function....i guess i must add event listenner load objectUrl / filename[i] in looping for but i can't figure how to do it

Comment: @Neversaysblack so your picking image from system  using browse file from option right <input type="file">  if possible can you give us html also then i can help you

Comment: please check my post again..hope it's clear enough...if not you can ask me again...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an eventListener for the "load" event of the image object, only then you will be able to get the image's width.

```
img.createEventListener("load", function() {
   alert(img.width);
})
```

Comment: i try to add event listener load before (objectUrl / filename[i] inside loop for)...but it's give result my script fail ( previewImage not show )...i will post what i tried before..can't you help fix it?